# How can I check the status of a tag wiki edit I submitted that must be reviewed?

Tags: support

I submitted a tag wiki edit for an empty tag wiki and haven't heard back yet, not can I figure out where to check on its status.  Thanks!!

Comment: Could you add a link / reference the tag in question?

Comment: Thanks, the tag in question is http://stackoverflow.com/tags/marklogic

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the `.../tags/name/info` [like for the support tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/support/info) (linked from the tag page as "about the name tag"), it should either show "your edit will be only visible to you until approved" (which means it is still waiting for someone with approval rights to come around), or the empty page as before your edit (which means it was rejected), or the new text (it was approved).

In the case of approval, you will also see +2 reputation in your reputation overview (if you didn't already collect 1000 rep by editing).

Comment: Thanks, there's nothing new at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/marklogic/info.  Should I have expected some interaction or a rejection notice?  I run the developer community at marklogic and I am hoping to promote use of stackoverflow and this tag in our community.  As precursor to my promotion of the tag, I was hoping to provide a small tag wiki.  I read thru the faq material and wrote up a small description of the tag based on that.  Is there any record of my submission or commentary on the rejection?  Without any feedback I'm finding it hard to figure out what to do next.

Comment: I don't see any rejection there, which probably means they are not recorded (or only visible for real moderators).